# Move HUE service into a different host

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue, cloudera-manager

I would like to move HUE between an host to a different one in my clouster, using Cloudera Manager .

It is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just delete the Hue service and re-add it and pick the host you want. And that's it! (everything will be re-configured/installed for you).

You can also do this at the instance level ('Instances' --> select and delete the Hue Server --> add it again).